# How to Implement Do nothing ExecuteAsync in Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, windows-services, .net-5

I am implementing a windows service, I don't want to write anything in the `ExecuteAsync` method. But when I keep it like the below, it shows a warning.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
}
```

**Warning**

> Warning   CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run
> synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await
> non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work
> on a background thread.

If I remove `async` It starts giving an error

> not all code paths return a value

So what is the best way to make the `ExecuteAsync` do nothing without any error and warning.

**Target framework:** .Net5

Comment: you can use --> await Task.CompletedTask;

Comment: @AvanthaSiriwardana Could you please explain that why will it work?

Comment: Since you do not return from that method, Task.CompletedTask is important when you need to return a dummy Task (that doesn't return a value/result) that's already completed. Please refer: https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/01/18/task-completedtask-and-task-result-tips.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `async` and return `Task.CompletedTask`. When you don't need `await` inside a method, remove the `async`. The code generated will be less overhead. *(with async the method is split-up into a state machine)*

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

---

Or shorter:

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) =>
    Task.CompletedTask;
```